# Different locus definitions of an ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are some different locus definitions of an ellipse other than the standard one that is taught in high school (Ellipse is the locus of points the sum of whose distance to the two given points is constant.)?

Comment: Try doing a search for "ellipse definition focus directrix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ellipse is the locus of points the ratio of whose distance to a fixed point(called focus) and whose distance to a fixed line(called directrix) is constant less than 1.
[image]

Comment: It is a nice definition. The only problem is that unless we allow the line at infinity, it leaves out the circles.